# In AngularJS how do I open download pdf in new Tab on iPad browser using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, button, tabs, angularjs-ng-click

On click of following button PDF download starts in the browser

```
<input name="SavNSend" class="gradient_button" id="printPdf" type="button" value="Save to PDF" ng-click="savePdfRP()"></input>
```

But what I want is to open a new tab in order to download the pdf. Can this be achieved using ng-click with button or ng-click with  tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a new tab/window. You need to use lower level services such as `$window`.

```
ng-click="savePdfRP()"

$scope.savePdfRP= function() {
    $window.open(url, windowName);
}
```

Another approach is to bind the href of the anchor.

```
<a class="gradient_button" id="printPdf" ng-href="{{ url }}" target="_blank">Save to PDF</a>

$scope.url = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I actually did this. And it works fine now.

<a href="#SaveNSend" id="printPdf" name="SavNSend" ng-click="savePdfRP()" class="gradient_button" target="_blank"> Save to PDF</a>